# How to make a custom-shaped Recycler View?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to make a recycler view whose elements will wrap around the ImageView (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg3cO.jpg). Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: RecyclerView is for scrolling data that enters and exits the screen. It is not appropriate for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create adapter with GridLayoutManager and for items with indexes 6, 7, 10, 11 make empty transparent views. But as it were said in comment it is not appropriate use of RV. Maybe it is better to stick with ordinary buttons, or make a custom composite view group.